Add TLS Authentication Credentials to gRPC Web fetch request
tl;dr How do I add TLS credentials to my gRPC web fetch request in TypeScript?
I have a backend server built using C++ and gRPC. I am now in the process of adding login feature to the backend with JWT. To do this, I have added an interceptor layer which runs an instance of an overridden AuthMetadataProcessor class which checks if the desired rpc service requires authentication (i.e., login wont but other services will). However, this wont work using insecure credentials. To solve this, I have added TLS keys and certificates to secure the backend. But now, my frontend (coded in TypeScript and Reactjs), fails to connect to the backend because it lacks the required credentials to perform a handshake with the backend.
How do I add these credentials to my fetch request?
btw. I am using proto-gen-js and ts-protoc-gen for my protobuf compiling into JavaScript and TypeScript respectively and a proxy for connecting to the backend.
This is how I am currently performing fetch requests to the backend using grpc.unary().
const WEB_HOSTNAME = process.env.WEB_HOSTNAME || window.location.hostname;
const GRPC_PORT = process.env.GRPC_PORT || 8082;
const GRPC_HOST = "http://" + WEB_HOSTNAME + ":" + GRPC_PORT;

type ServiceFunctionName = keyof Omit<
  typeof Service,
  "serviceName" | "prototype"
>;

export async function grpcFetch<
  RequestType extends ProtobufMessage,
  ResponseType extends ProtobufMessage,
>(
  request: RequestType,
  serviceFunctionName: ServiceFunctionName
): Promise<ResponseType> {
  const response: ResponseType = await unaryRequest<RequestType, ResponseType>(
    Service[serviceFunctionName],
    request
  );
  return response;
}

function unaryRequest<
  Request extends ProtobufMessage,
  Response extends ProtobufMessage,
>(serviceFunction: (typeof Service)[ServiceFunctionName], request: Request) {
  return new Promise<Response>(
    (
      resolve: (value: Response | PromiseLike<Response>) => void,
      reject: (reason?: string | UnaryOutput<Response>) => void
    ) => {
      // The gRPC fetch request metadata.
      const metaData: grpc.Metadata.ConstructorArg = new grpc.Metadata({
        "grpc-timeout": "30S",
      });
      // The gRPC fetch request props.
      const props: UnaryRpcOptions<Request, Response> = {
        request: request,
        host: GRPC_HOST,
        metadata: metaData,
        onEnd: (res: UnaryOutput<Response>) => {
          if (res.status === grpc.Code.OK && res.message) {
            resolve(res.message);
          }

          const isNoServerConnection: boolean =
            Object.keys(res.headers.headersMap).length === 0;

          if (isNoServerConnection) {
            reject("Could not connect to backend");
          }
          reject(res);
        },
      };
      // The actual request to the gRPC backend.
      grpc.unary(
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        serviceFunction as any,
        props
      );
    }
  );
}

UPDATE: I found an answer. As far as I am aware, you cannot add TLS authentication credentials between gRPC web client and a gRPC server as mentioned in this issue. However, you can add TLS authentication credentials between the gRPC proxy and the gRPC server. This completes the handshake and allows you to use the AuthMetadataProcessor class. How to implement TLS on the proxy depends on the proxy you are using.
